# Can't install mysql server on windows

Tags: mysql, windows-10

I'm trying to install a mysql server on my win 10 machine. I've downloaded the installer from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/), but when I open it, it finds an installed version of mysql server on my computer (which I thought I had uninstalled something like a month ago). I tried to remove it from the installer, but it fails when it reaches 50%, and I also cannot find any mysql file on my computer. Can anyone of you help me removing the thing I have on my computer to make a new fresh install on mysql server, please?

Thanks,

Lorenzo

Comment: use this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnOnzNQnJMU

Comment: this is way too broad imo - are there any error messages? Also, may be off-topic and better suiter for super user SE

Comment: @RishabhKSharma the problem is that when I open the installer, it doesn't prompt the things that are shown in the video, it lists the installed packages

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs it only says 

"1: The action 'Remove' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.13' failed."

Comment: @LorenzoFioroni then manually delete everything?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs thanks for the advice, I try to repost in SuperUser site

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I've tried, but I can't find any file linked with it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on [su] - https://superuser.com/questions/1372151/cant-install-mysql-server-on-windows-10/1372163#1372163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://superuser.com/questions/1372151/cant-install-mysql-server-on-windows-10/1372163#1372163) is the solution to my problem. I managed to uninstall the previous version with FixIt and than I did a new installation. Thanks to all of you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove directory Mysql found in from C:\Program Files (x86) or C:\Program Files.
 and try Install mysql agai